# Error importing random and string modules with eclipse and grinder

Tags: python, eclipse, jython, grinder

I have a grinder script. The script is working without errors but when I want to import the string and random modules the following error is thrown:

```
2015-01-06 15:51:48,356 ERROR PCAA-0: aborting process - Java exception initialising test script
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: Java exception initialising test script
File "C:\Grinder\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar\re$py.class", line 279, in <module>
File "C:\Grinder\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar\string$py.class", line 81, in <module>
import string
File "C:\Users\net_user\workspace\Grinder\grinder_1.py", line 2, in <module>
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at org.python.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) ~[jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:na]
at org.python.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:na]
at org.python.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:na]
at org.python.core.AnnotationReader.<init>(AnnotationReader.java:44) ~[jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:na]
at org.python.core.imp.readCode(imp.java:219) ~[jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:na]
```

I'm using Eclipse with grinderstone plugin to run the scripts. The interpreter is set to Jython. jython interpreter settings:

[image]

Pythonpath:

[image]

I can't figure why I can't use the random and string modules. The modules are imported in IDLE and no errors are thrown. Full log [here](http://pastebin.com/iNWy7Qah)